# Adjust query according to drop down selection

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

What I am trying to get is this:

I have the following variables in my php file:

```
$tech= $_GET['Combobox10'];
$shopfloor = $_GET['Combobox8'];
```

What I would like to do is if from the HTML form for example the variable $tech (which is a drop down) is selected as 'all' then the following query must run showing all Tech in the table - as if the Having part related to Tech of the sql query does not exist. The same for $shopfloor - if the drop down selected is 'all' I want the query to ignore the having part of the $shopfloor and show all. Of course if a particular shop floor or tech is selected then the Having part of the query must be enforced.

```
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM dbo_shopfloorcells INNER JOIN (dbo_noted_by INNER JOIN (dbo_leader_name INNER JOIN (dbo_Station INNER JOIN (dbo_Shop_Floor INNER JOIN (dbo_Fault_Desc INNER JOIN 
(dbo_Machine INNER JOIN (dbo_Line_Cell_Binding INNER JOIN (dbo_Tech_Name INNER JOIN (dbo_Maint_Category INNER JOIN dbo_newprevlog2 ON dbo_Maint_Category.ID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Maint_Cat) 
ON dbo_Tech_Name.ID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Tech_Name) ON dbo_Line_Cell_Binding.PKID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Line_Desc) ON dbo_Machine.PKID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Mach_Desc) 
ON dbo_Fault_Desc.ID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Fault_Desc) ON dbo_Shop_Floor.ID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Shop_Floor) ON dbo_Station.PKID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Station_No) 
ON dbo_leader_name.ID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Leader_Name) ON dbo_noted_by.ID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Noted_By) ON (dbo_shopfloorcells.PKID = dbo_Line_Cell_Binding.ID_Cell_Shop_Floor) 
AND (dbo_shopfloorcells.ID_Shop_Floor = dbo_Shop_Floor.ID)
GROUP BY dbo_newprevlog2.ID, dbo_newprevlog2.Status, dbo_Shop_Floor.Shopfloor, dbo_shopfloorcells.Cell, dbo_Line_Cell_Binding.Line_Name, 
dbo_Machine.Machine_Section, dbo_Station.Station_, dbo_Tech_Name.Technician_Name, dbo_Maint_Category.Maintenance_Category, dbo_Fault_Desc.Fault_Description, 
dbo_newprevlog2.Intervention, dbo_newprevlog2.Remarks, dbo_newprevlog2.ComponentsParts, dbo_newprevlog2.StartDate1, dbo_newprevlog2.EndDate1, dbo_newprevlog2.StartTime1, 
dbo_newprevlog2.EndTime1, dbo_newprevlog2.DurationTime, dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Shop_Floor, dbo_Line_Cell_Binding.ID_Cell_Shop_Floor
having (dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Shop_Floor = $shopfloor) AND ((dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Tech_Name = $tech));");
```

I have no idea how to go about this. I have tried changing the $tech for example to this (thanks to user @Déjà vu from this forum):

```
$tech = ($_GET['Combobox10'] != "all") ? $_GET['Combobox10'] : '';
```

But it is not giving me the required result for this occasion.

Comment: what is the value of $tech after that last assignment?

Answer (score 0):

#### Method 1

Try the following

```
$tech = ($_GET['Combobox10'] != "all") ? $_GET['Combobox10'] : "dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Tech_Name";

$shopfloor = ($_GET['Combobox8'] != "all") ? $_GET['Combobox8'] : "dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Shop_Floor";
```

or

```
$tech = ($_GET['Combobox10'] != "all") ? $_GET['Combobox10'] : true;

$shopfloor = ($_GET['Combobox8'] != "all") ? $_GET['Combobox8'] : true;
```

The idea is to just skip the check (`having`) in the last line of your `mysql_query`, and make them always true.

---

#### Method 2 (Recommended)

Though a better solution would have been altering your `mysql_query` altogether, skipping those checks.

Alter your sql query *(Modified after your comment to suit your needs)*

Notice the $check part actually decides which SQL query parameters would be applied depending on whether one or both of the combobox were selected "all".

```
$check = "";
    if ($tech != "all" or $shopfloor != "all") $check .= "having ";
    if ($tech != "all") $check .= "(dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Tech_Name = ".$tech.")";
    if ($tech != "all" and $shopfloor != "all") $check .= " AND ";
    if ($shopfloor != "all") $check .= "(dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Shop_Floor = ".$shopfloor.")";
    
    $result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM dbo_shopfloorcells INNER JOIN (dbo_noted_by INNER JOIN (dbo_leader_name INNER JOIN (dbo_Station INNER JOIN (dbo_Shop_Floor INNER JOIN (dbo_Fault_Desc INNER JOIN 
    (dbo_Machine INNER JOIN (dbo_Line_Cell_Binding INNER JOIN (dbo_Tech_Name INNER JOIN (dbo_Maint_Category INNER JOIN dbo_newprevlog2 ON dbo_Maint_Category.ID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Maint_Cat) 
    ON dbo_Tech_Name.ID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Tech_Name) ON dbo_Line_Cell_Binding.PKID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Line_Desc) ON dbo_Machine.PKID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Mach_Desc) 
    ON dbo_Fault_Desc.ID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Fault_Desc) ON dbo_Shop_Floor.ID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Shop_Floor) ON dbo_Station.PKID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Station_No) 
    ON dbo_leader_name.ID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Leader_Name) ON dbo_noted_by.ID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Noted_By) ON (dbo_shopfloorcells.PKID = dbo_Line_Cell_Binding.ID_Cell_Shop_Floor) 
    AND (dbo_shopfloorcells.ID_Shop_Floor = dbo_Shop_Floor.ID)
    GROUP BY dbo_newprevlog2.ID, dbo_newprevlog2.Status, dbo_Shop_Floor.Shopfloor, dbo_shopfloorcells.Cell, dbo_Line_Cell_Binding.Line_Name, 
    dbo_Machine.Machine_Section, dbo_Station.Station_, dbo_Tech_Name.Technician_Name, dbo_Maint_Category.Maintenance_Category, dbo_Fault_Desc.Fault_Description, 
    dbo_newprevlog2.Intervention, dbo_newprevlog2.Remarks, dbo_newprevlog2.ComponentsParts, dbo_newprevlog2.StartDate1, dbo_newprevlog2.EndDate1, dbo_newprevlog2.StartTime1, 
    dbo_newprevlog2.EndTime1, dbo_newprevlog2.DurationTime, dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Shop_Floor, dbo_Line_Cell_Binding.ID_Cell_Shop_Floor".$check.";");
```

And no change is required for this

```
$tech= $_GET['Combobox10'];
$shopfloor = $_GET['Combobox8'];
```

Comment: yes I can follow your last solution (altering the SQL query) however how can i get this to work with other variables in the same query? Hence I also need to bypass AND as in HAVING .... AND...?

Comment: @elstiv take a look once again, I've updated the code, based on your comment, and added how it would work just above the code. Tell me if it suits your needs.